# Object Oriented Design - Should first class collections / encapsulated collections implement collection/IEnumerable interfaces?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, encapsulation

I am a fan of Jeff Bay's Object Calisthenics exercise:

http://www.xpteam.com/jeff/writings/objectcalisthenics.rtf

and I have had good results implementing first class collections by creating objects to encapsulate both the implementation of the collection and also the iteration over collections of objects.

This means instead of a List I have a EmployeeList object.

Typically when I create these objects, I don't implement any collection interfaces so external users cannot enumerate the inner collection, as I thought this was the whole point. However, one colleague was suggesting the opposite - implement ICollect interface to make it more flexible.

This refactoring site seems to be in the same direction, although it doesn't completely remove access to the inner collection: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/encapsulate-collection

```
    // Foreach method
    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        if (employee.IsManager)
        {
            managers.Add(employee);
        }
    }

    // Linq method
    managers = employees.Where(e => e.IsManager);


    // Encapsulated iteration method
    managers = employees.GetAllManagers();

    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllManagers() // Inside Employees class
    {
        return employees.Where(e => e.IsManager);
    }
```

Am I right in saying the last method is favourable? When would you ever want to expose your inner collection by implementing IEnumerable for example?

Comment: `GetAllManagers()` does make sense, but it returns an `IEnumerable` anyway.  In other words, it's just a convenience method; it provides filtering which the client can accomplish himself anyway, if he has access to the original collection.  These kinds of methods can also be used for security, if you don't want the client to have access to the entire collection.

Comment: It only seems like a (mere) convenience method with the above (simple) implementation. If the implementation was more complex and you found multiple places the same lines of implementation was pasted across your codebase then that would violate DRY, right? Similarly, if the inner collection's implementation changed, e.g. if it must go to a database to fetch the information, you would want to ensure clients batch fetch all the employees first rather than doing 1 sql call per employee. This detail is best wrapped on the list object, rather than forced onto clients, surely?

Comment: It depends on how sophisticated your users are.  DRY notwithstanding, your last example with the `Where` clause is a very common pattern in repository objects.  It's not redundant if the filtering is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`IEnumerable` would probably be a good choice. You could have a private list of your `Employee` object, and expose it publicly as an `IEnumerable` to let people use it in loops, LINQ, etc.

Since `IEnumerable` doesn't allow you to modify the collection being iterated over, you don't have to worry about the consumer of your `EmployeeList` changing the internals.

Providing an iteration method wouldn't be as ideal, since it breaks [POLA](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment), and requires some effort on the programmer consuming the API to find the method he wants to call. Thinking about it, you'd never have code like the following in .NET.

```
var list = new List<T>;
foreach (var item in list.GetAllItems())
{
    // Whut? 
}
```

Comment: Why would I want people to iterate through it manually in loops and LINQ, rather than providing the methods to do what they want myself? Especially if iterating is expensive and has to go to a database, etc. You'd be better off batch fetching the objects first then filtering, which you'd have to implement in every client call and again would be better encapsulated on the collection object.

Comment: @MichaelParker, if you think you can provide all of the methods that anyone will ever want to call on your data, I'm pretty sure you're wrong. Instead of imagining all of the specific situations someone might be interested in, and thinking you know better, it's better to provide people access to the information and let *them* decide how to use it.

Comment: I didn't realize you were going for more of an [active record pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) or [repository pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)... I thought this was strictly a collection that you'd create once with results from a database query. Even still, you can cache results obtained from the database implicitly for the consumer and filter/iterate through those.

Comment: @WayneWerner are you saying exposing data is better than providing behaviours? That sounds like the opposite of OOP. If you can't encapsulate all necessary behaviours on your objects then I'd suspect the objects are too big and not single responsibility.

Comment: @JeffBridgman True, I can cache results as we go, unfortunately providing an iterator without an explicit filter doesn't allow me to optimise for list-wide operations, for example optimising DB queries and batch fetching objects (but there are many other list-wide optimisations you may want to make, even excluding database access). If the behaviour is explicitly called out as a function I can deal with list-wide behaviours and optimisations which seems a good reason for the list object to exist rather than be bypassed.

Comment: Gotcha. Functions sounds like they may be useful in this case then. Maybe some of the patterns I linked to above will be helpful.

Comment: @MichaelParker The behavior of a random access collection is that you can iterate over it. OTOH, if your class is not meant to represent a collection of that nature, then you are correct. Don't mistake implementing IEnumerable with exposing data - *your* implementation of IEnumerable could return '4' everytime, if that was the thing to do.

Comment: @WayneWerner I don't know why you'd have an object with a private inner collection which implemented `IEnumerable` and didn't iterate over the inner collection - that would certainly violate principle of least surprise and would be much better off on a well named function such as `GetTheNumber4()` :) Can you think of an example where this would actually be sensible? (Other than framework/generic collections - I'm talking about the domain layer)

Comment: @MichaelParker, What's inside the class (implementation wise) is irrelevant. That's why you *have* a class. I haven't ever had a need to produce less than all of the values in a collection, and I can't think of one. But I'm sure there *is* one.